# Bootstrap navbar: menu how to keep the tab highlighted?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started working on DW (last version), (I used bootstrap component: "basic navbar" to insert the menu)
but I realize as soon as I click on a tab, it loads the page for me, but the tab does not remain highlighted.

Rem: (the "hover" works very well): as soon as I hover over the tabs the color changes well,
and so I would like it to keep for example this same color when the tab remains active so that the user knows
in which menu it is found.
I posted the code (generated by DW) but I'm not sure what to change in the code ??? and in the css?
Surprising all the same that this basic principle is not set by default in the component ??
In my css I just have the "hover" part.

Thank you for your advice because I've been struggling with this pb for several days (yet it seems to me to be a fairly common behavior ... !!!)

```css
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="compotest.php">Assistance</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="evenementsVU.html">Evènements</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bulletins</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="bulletin125.htm">Dernier bulletin</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="collection.php">Bulletins archivés</a>

    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="inscriptionform.php">Adhésion</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="liens.php">Liens</a> </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: If I have understood you correct, you want the link to be highlighted on the page where user is in. Try out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948762/13833218). Let me know if it doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: Avec votre solution, il me montre l’onglet actif par défaut mis en surbrillance mais dès que je clique sur un autre onglet, il ne le conserve pas. Pourquoi mon code est-il devenu illisible, les caractères semblent être dupliqués ???

Comment: Can you please say that in english please?

Comment: So, you have the navbar code in every page right? Change the `active` class to the appropriate link

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me because for several days I really can't do it ... !!!

Right, I have an include in each page that includes the navigation bar code.
But I don't understand when you say "replace active class with appropriate link ..." "??

Rem: Sorry but it is impossible for me to write in English (I have to re-translate everything)

Comment: What I mean by replace is this. According to your code sample, In your navbar code in `index.php` add the `active` class only to the `nav-link` which says "Accueil". This will highlight "Accueil" in `index.php`. Then add `active` class only to the `nav-link` which says "Assistance"  in the navbar of your `compotest.php`. This will highlight "Assistance" in `compotest.php`. Replace this appropriately according to the page name in navbar. I hope you could understand!!

Comment: If you find my answer useful and it solves your problem consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you so much...!!! it works !! :-))
It's been several days that I was on this problem ... !!, I had tried several things:
toggle (tab-content), javascript,. (besides I thought there was a solution with JS) .. in short, nothing worked
The small inconvenience is as my menu was in an include, I am now obliged to repeat the new code "hard"
in each program ... but too bad but I noticed that he does not take this into account (my color in my css), besides I do not really know where he will get the color from
(to highlight the tab).

Another big thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `active` class for the `nav-link`. As per the documentation,

> Add the `.active` class on `.nav-link` to indicate the current page.

Refer more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#nav)

In your example if you want the `nav-link` "Accueil" to be highlighted if the user is in `index.php` add the `active` class in the HTML as below.

```
 <li class="nav-item"> 
     <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Accueil</a>
 </li>
```

Try the following snippet

```css
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="compotest.php">Assistance</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="evenementsVU.html">Evènements</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bulletins</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="bulletin125.htm">Dernier bulletin</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="collection.php">Bulletins archivés</a>

    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="inscriptionform.php">Adhésion</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="liens.php">Liens</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! Indeed, it works for tabs: as soon as I change tab, this time it remains well highlighted but my pages are not loaded ... I did not quite understand the fact of adding the "#" before the names of my pages to load but how can he load them in this case??? or there's something I really didn't understand???

I posted you my code readapted according to your template (only for the first 3 tabs)